# Defining union types using top-down recursion in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have these type definitions:

```
type Module<T, C extends Children> = {
    metaData: T;
    children: C;
};

type Children = {
    [key: string]: Module<any, any>;
}

type ExtractMetaData<M extends Module<any, any>> = M extends Module<infer T, any> ? T : never;

type ExtractChildren<M extends Module<any, any>> = M extends Module<any, infer C> ? C : never;
```

Basically, nested modules. Each module has some metadata (just an arbitrary type in this case, in my actual project it's something more complex) and an object mapping strings to child/nested modules.

What I want is a utility type that will generate a union type of all of the `MetaData` types of a module & its children.

So let's say module A has metadata of type `string`, module B has metadata of type `boolean`, and module C has metadata of type `number`. Module C is the child of module B which is in turn a child of Module A.

Therefore, this utility type for Module C should return just the type `number`, for Module B should return `number | boolean`, and for Module A should return `number | boolean | string`.

This is what I have so far:

```
type AllTypes<
  MODULE extends Module<any, any>,
  CHILDREN = ExtractChildren<MODULE>,
  METADATA = ExtractMetaData<MODULE>,
> =
  | METADATA
  | {
      [KEY in keyof CHILDREN]: CHILDREN[KEY] extends Module<any, any>
        ? ExtractMetaData<MODULE>
        : never;
    }[keyof CHILDREN];
```

Basically, I'm using top-down recursion to generate a union (I think).

My first question is, does this even work in theory? Does this generate the union type like I'm expecting?

My second question is regarding infinite recursion. As I worried, when I try to use this utility type, the TS compiler will sometimes complain that "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite." I see why it's worried about infinite recursion, but I'm not sure how to get around this.

Is there a better way of writing this utility type? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAvORW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. (For example: you mention modules `A`, `B`, `C` but do not show them, nor do you show what `AllTypes<A>`/`AllTypes<B>` evaluates to. You say "the TS compiler will sometimes complain", but are not showing that happen.)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the feedback - I've posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539504/typescript-type-recursion-over-object

Comment: You can and should [edit] a question instead of abandoning it in favor of making a new post. But since you’ve already created another post, maybe you should delete this one?