# Typescript type recursion over object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have these definitions for a Module, which contains a `MetaData` type and an object that maps arbitrary names to child/nested Modules:

```
type Module<T, C extends Children> = {
    metaData: T;
    children: C;
};

type Children = {
    [key: string]: Module<any, any>;
}

type ExtractMetaData<M extends Module<any, any>> = M extends Module<infer T, any> ? T : never;

type ExtractChildren<M extends Module<any, any>> = M extends Module<any, infer C> ? C : never;
```

Now, let's say I define three simple modules, A, B, and C, so that C is a child of B and B is a child of A:

```
type C = Module<number, {}>;

type B = Module<boolean, {
  c: C;
}>;

type A = Module<string, {
  b: B;
}>;
```

What I want is a utility type `AllMetaData<T extends Module>` that will return a union of all the `MetaData` types in a Module tree. For example, `AllMetaData<C>` is the type `number`, `AllMetaData<B>` is the type `number | boolean`, and `AllMetaData<A>` is the type `number | boolean | string`.

Here's what I have:

```
type AllMetaData<
  MODULE extends Module<any, any>,
  CHILDREN = ExtractChildren<MODULE>,
  METADATA = ExtractMetaData<MODULE>,
> =
  | METADATA
  | {
      [KEY in keyof CHILDREN]: CHILDREN[KEY] extends Module<any, any>
        ? ExtractMetaData<MODULE>
        : never;
    }[keyof CHILDREN];
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because when I define this type:

```
type Result = AllMetaData<A>;
```

`Result` is equivalent to `string`, when it should be a union of all the `MetaData` types in A's tree.

Why doesn't my `AllMetadata` type work?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAshYBDAIqtAeAUFKRAeXQFUAZAUSggA9gIA7AEwGdCB7ZgVzgm1SMQAGiiCQAPmH4oAYQASASXLoASpQByUALxRK9AE6oAxsFkALAJZxmBptmJkqUmYkoAVGOhiedewybAyGiYOI4UlC4SOjIAPoQeXj4wcVAA3jIEBADaANKUAJpQloxQANYQIBwAZnJKKuoaALoAXHXKapp5hU009ExsnDx8AkKi4hKZWQQA-P7ARqbBGFioDiQRk9PTbYwQAG4QBgDcUwC%202RVVtQodjU2nuLigkEO8-O6isn0MLOwW1lsTGiugy0wAtigVmg2u5TtNjFYbHZGG1ZKczo8XtAAcimH4wVlLpU2qwFiUAOatN4jcTjIQSDFPbHzRZBKGhNaIH4DdiILjvUYiMQMkGEHl-Gn8ErVI5QT4iyRQObuKC7A5HLHgaD6BaBXFAxgOCWDfnDfh0xUSMXcui-U0C2ljYqMWUGOTRObfdWHE7M7VyPxmwWMbjggBGR1EaTOjP9rwAQkHHfxwxwOHxBNGZMY0Ri488AzBk%20bsGSDJTswRw20E-mta9VBBWLxgH54EgOatsDAC8YOIwyVBQ%20C2k2W3A27oAKzHIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes.

1. line 9 should use `CHILDREN[KEY]` instead of `MODULE`
2. line 9 should use `AllMetaData` instead of `ExtractMetaData`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwK4BsIB4AqAaKBhKCAD2AgDsEBnfACwEsUEAncgPigF4oBvAKCigBbCMACGAEVFiAXFEwBuflADG9RizKy8igL6LeoSLQbNynHkoDaAawghZlYEzpkA5gF1Z8ZGnSiyILj+IKy6vAbg0ACCKCgwIhJSoliEJORUsIioGMFBAazsXJiWAOTCYpJiJe5KAD4WAgKWANJQLlC2IHAAZnKlqiYa1Z5QMXEJlcnFJQPq5NUt7qxKOjZ2PX0zaqZkw+GG0ARc3tnoZEiCAEYQTLjcOqH7kVAAQuYnvpdwcGj+d0rKLS6R4RIxRd5ZXyOZxuf4CS6yF7A-QHKAAJQglFQwHMY3iFSS6CiIOUcDIjig50EsgxWJQOK4AFZ5EA)

Comment: Oops, silly mistakes. Unfortunately I didn't make these errors in my original project, and I'm getting a "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" error there. However, my types are a little more complicated in my project, so I'll just have to make another post